# server refused our key while logging into putty

Tags: xubuntu

i was changed the home directory permission to 777, after that i tried to login but it's displaying "server refused our key". Please give me the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you make SSH connection from terminal with `-i`?

Comment: Could you please explore it

Comment: Raghavendra, in the future, please try to include information in your question so people don't have to guess or ask what you mean. For example, you imply, but never state, *"I tried to fix it, but I wasn't able to login again."* Other things that it would have been helpful to have in your question: whether you know a password for the account, whether you are the sysadmin, what command exactly did you use (e.g., `chmod -R 777 ~`), and what other changes did you make at the same time? (Oh, and a small tip: it sounds more polite to say "Please help" than "Please give me the solution.")

Answer (score 0):

Probably the private key file is too open for ssh. I had a similiar error a few days ago.
You have to set the permissions in the ~/.ssh directory to be more secure.
Try:

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_*
chmod 644 ~/.ssh/id_*.pub
```

Comment: i know only server login username, can you please tell me how to solve this through putty.

Comment: How to change ssh file permissions without login into server, because while login only it's displaying "Server refused our key". Please let me know ASAP

Comment: It seems I misunderstood you. I thought your home directory on your PC was changed and not on the server.If the server refuses the connection with a key than you only can login with username+password.

Comment: Please find the below Screen http://imagizer.imageshack.com/img922/9908/v1aUmx.jpg Like this i have to login? Please let me know ASAP

Comment: No. Just type root and hit enter. Than putty should prompt for the password. Enter it there.

Comment: When i'm login with "root", it's displaying like "Authenticating with public key "**************"
Please login as the user "ubuntu" rather than the user "root".
"
http://imagizer.imageshack.com/img922/5045/sYh9Ie.jpg

Comment: Are you the sysadmin of the server you are trying to log into?

Comment: @hackerb9 i'm php Dev. but we are only maintaining servers. Please tell me how to solve the issue

Comment: Probably the user root doesn't allow login. This is normally the configuration with Ubuntu Servers. You have a sudo user that can later become root.